# MemSQL speed test VS dbbench speed test

Tags: singlestore

I'm running MemSQL speed test which shows **638K inserts per second** (in the web UI).

Likewise I'm running dbbench benchmark tool in order to simulate the same load, however I get throughput of only **20K inserts per sec**. (dbbench is run on the same machine as MemSQL)

I'm confused, is there something that I'm missing?

Here is how I run dbbench:

```
dbbench --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 dbbench.ini*
```

dbbench.ini:

```
[setup]
query=CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS speed_test
query=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS speed_test.tbl (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, val INT)

[teardown]
query=DROP DATABASE speed_test

[inserts]
query=insert into speed_test.tbl (val) values(5)
concurrency=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Running single-value inserts will be much slower than multi-inserts, and concurrency 10 is much too low to saturate the cluster as well. The bottleneck for your workload in the dbbench config here will be in all these round-trips which are doing very little work in the database.

Try:

- batching more values into each insert statement
- increasing the concurrency

Comment: I've batched 100 row values in 1 insert, throughput has increased to 100K/sec, however when comparing to MySQL in memory table, one row single insert appears to be about 100 times faster. Why is that?

Comment: One reason is probably because of the additional network latency in MemSQL, since it is a distributed database, and the insert needs to go from the client to the aggregator to the leaf.